# How to pass in the state of my app from App.js to MainStack.Screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have my App.js which then renders a NavigationContainer with MainStack.Screen(s). I use an api to fetch some data about movies and then process it to give me a list of movieItem Objects with details about that movie. I save this moviesList object in my App.js state and want to pass this to my HomeScreen so that it can render all the movies in the moviesList object.

Please help how I can correctly get the route.params.moviesList[0].title to show.

```
App.js:

import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import ResultsScreen from './Screens/ResultsScreen';

import { fetchMovies } from './api';

const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    moviesList: null,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers = async () => {
    const movies = await fetchMovies();
    this.setState({ moviesList: movies });
    console.log('===========');
    console.log(this.state.moviesList);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MainStack.Navigator>
          <MainStack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            initialParams={this.state}
          />
          <MainStack.Screen name="Results" component={ResultsScreen} />
        </MainStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

```
HomeScreen.js:

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Row from '../Row';

export default function HomeScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  console.log('ROUTE:');
  console.log(route);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>Movie Browser</Text>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>{route.params.moviesList[0].title}</Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder="Sreach" />
      <Row props />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 42,
    padding: 20,
  },
  text: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    fontSize: 24,
    paddingBottom: 5,
  },
  textInput: {
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    minWidth: 260,
    marginBottom: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
});
```

Comment: You can use React Context api or Redux, MobX or any other state management library

Comment: Are you sure , the route.params is an array not an object? Just making sure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `movieList` array is your params. Try this in your return statement of HomeScreen.js:

```
 <Text style={styles.heading}>{route.params[0].title}</Text>
```